# gracenote c++ wrapper error: gnsdk_taste.h is missed

Tags: gracenote

I'm trying to write simple app based on GNSDK, which will be using c++ wrapper. And I have error - after I including "gnsdk.hpp" compiler could not find gnsdk_taste.h. I was trying to find it in GNSDK folder, but could not. Could someone please help me to solve issue?

Comment: Can you try removing gnsdk_taste.h from gnsdk.hpp? You are not going to use gnsdk_taste anyway as the corresponding lib is not included.

Comment: Thanks, It work for me. But it was a little bit strange - I have downloaded GNSDK from official site, and it contains such little bug.

Comment: Can you accept a comment as and answer? Also would you be so kind and let me know the exact version or name of the package you downloaded? I'll get it corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Remove gnsdk_taste.h from gnsdk.hpp. You are not going to use gnsdk_taste anyway as the corresponding lib is not included.